# Logo responsivo que funcione em todos os browsers usando CSS3 e Bootstrap

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Quero que quando minimizo a janela o logo do meu site acompanhe sem distorcer, tal como quando se testa um site em telemovel ou tablet, ou seja que a imagem seja responsiva ao conteudo, mas isto só me acontece no internet explorer, no chrome e no firefox já funciona bem!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

html:

```
<div class="banner">

            <img class="seven-logo" src="img/7a_logo_center3.png"  alt="logo_centro">
    </div>
```

CSS3

```
img.seven-logo{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  /*RESPONSIVE_IMAGE PARA FIREFOX*/
@-moz-document url-prefix() {  
    img.seven-logo{
     width: 100%;
     max-width:600px;
     max-height:156px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, estava mal editado. Consegues ajudar? talvez um hack parecido para IE como o que usei para o Firefox?

Comment: Não está claro o que você está pergunta. Edite a pergunta, reduza o título e nos dê mais detalhes no corpo da postagem.

Comment: Espero ter sido mais claro?

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara ainda, detalhe exatamente o problema em questão, o que acontece no IE que funciona no Firefox, mas por enquanto aqui está um fiddle que fiz sobre um banner centralizado e responsivo com Css (sem hacks): http://jsfiddle.net/vFQNa/

Comment: Espero que a imagem em cima ajude a compreender

Comment: Leonardo Obrigado! o meu logo já é responsivo em IE o problema era que nas propriedades além do max-width tive também que definir apenas a largura!

Answer (score 2):

No bootstrap existem alguns helpers que podem te servir muito bem durante o desenvolvimento do projeto, e de momento você pode utilizar a classe **[.img-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive)**. Essa classe irá tratar "automaticamente" a largura da sua imagem e adaptando de acordo com a tela.

***HTML***

```
<img src="http://content4.viralnova.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/sony-logo.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

Você pode ver o exemplo nesta **[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/G0wxG0lo8G)** (clique no icone mobile para testar diferentes tamanhos)

O ideal para dispositivos mobiles é diminuir o trafego de dados com a sua página, usando ***Media queries*** e criar tamanhos diferentes para o logo, com certeza adaptação será muito melhor e o desempenho também.

***CSS***

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .logo {
        width:200px;
        height:80px;
        background:url("images/logo/200.png");
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .logo {
        width:400px;
        height:220px;
        background:url("images/logo/400.png");
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .logo {
        width:800px;
        height:440px;
        background:url("images/logo/800.png");
    }
}
```

Este é apenas um exemplo de como poderia ser feito.

Comment: Sim já tinha visto, mas por algum motivo no firefox não funcionava. Obrigado ;)

Comment: @Schismatick experimente colocar `width:100%;`

Comment: outra solução porem gambiarra é colocar a classe `.col-xs-12` no seu logo.

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhada nesse plugin, ele redimensiona as divs corretamente.

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/